# modprobe: FATAL: Module dm_mod not found in directory /lib/modules/6.6.16

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, kernel-parameters, grub2-mkconfig

I have built a custom kernel and given a CONFIG_LOCALVERSION of `-grant-nvme` during compilation. However, when I try to boot into it, no matter what I do, grub seems to look for `/lib/modules/6.6.16` and I cannot for the life of me figure out where it is pulling 6.6.16 from. It should be looking in `6.6.16-grant-nvme`. I have checked a dozen times that CONFIG_LOCALVERSION is set correctly during compilation, the boot entries for GRUB have it set correctly, the correct name exists both in /lib/modules and /boot/vmlinuz-6.6.16-grant-nvme yet for some reason GRUB persists in booting to the folder 6.6.16 vanilla.

Where is it pulling that from? How do I direct it to the correct folder?

Full error is:

```
[ 6.174579] systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
[ 6.494351] dracut-pre-udev[499]: modprobe: FATAL: Module dm_mod not found in directory /lib/modules/6.6.16
```

Sure enough, when I drop to dracut, I see:

```
dracut:/# ls /lib/modules
6.6.16-grant-nvme
```

### Update

I also tried `dracut --force --kver 6.6.16-grant-nvme /boot/initramfs-6.6.16-grant-nvme.img`

### Update 2

Came back to this with fresh eyes today and ran strings on `vmlinuz`. Here is what is odd to me; the kernel build string is `6.6.16 (root@nvme.lan) (gcc (GCC) 11.4.1 20230605 (Red Hat 11.4.1-2), GNU ld version 2.35.2-42.el9) #2 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Feb 15 08:10:42 EST 2024`

This clearly does not have my `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`. I am going to go back through the kernel build process again and see if somehow it didn't take. The thing is, the folder names in /boot are correct which I can only imagine happens if it is reading `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`

Comment: I would be inclined to run `/usr/bin/dracut --force boot/initramfs-6.6.16-grant-nvme.img 6.6.16-grant-nvme`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going back, saving my config, doing a `make clean`, `make mrproper`, `make distclean`.

After that I restored my config and just built again and it worked. I don't know exactly what was going wrong because in `/boot` the names were all correct, but it seems like the actual kernel build itself was somehow picking up something without config localversion.

After I reset absolutely everything it worked.